# SWT Browser Problem on Vista

Tags: java, internet-explorer, browser, swt

We're running Java Swing and are using an SWT bridge to get ahold of the SWT browser. Everything normally works just fine, but we have a problem on a Vista test machine. It worked fine until just a week ago or so. The call stack:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3589)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3481)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:3452)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.IE.create(IE.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Browser.java:109)
    ...
```

I have tried IE7 and IE8 through the SWT browser, but none is working (XULRunner is not applicable on our application since we need two browser instances).

XP, Windows7 and Vista is working on other machines, and I can't exclude something being correpted on this specific machine. We got some Windows updates close to when this error started happening, they seem related. It is a our only Vista test machine with a virtual screen, has there been any Windows updates for IE relating to virtual screens that could cause this? To me it looks like a likely target for security holes, so maybe that could be it?

I know this is looking for a needle in a haystack, but has anybody seen anything similar lately?

Comment: It seems as u have opened Too many Browser and the OS cant handle anymore. Does it works when you restart your computer?
Did you dispose the browser ?

Comment: I open a single browser. The problem only happens on Vista. Rebooted a dozen times. I did disopse the browser (but then I never tried to "restart" the browser afterwards).

Answer (score -4, accepted):

My solution is not to embed the SWTBrowser into our Swing application at all. (I've always hated web tech on desktop apps anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: looking at [the source](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.swt/Eclipse%20SWT%20Browser/win32/org/eclipse/swt/browser/IE.java?revision=1.52&view=markup), I see that the `IE.create` method swallows an exception to throw this error - I'd step into the `WebSite` constructor to try and figure out what's happening.

Comment: Good suggestion, too bad it quickly led into the deep OLE swamp. I'll keep blaming it on Vista SP2 for now. :)

Comment: See this comment for hints on how to gather info if you're going to submit a bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=207252#c2